# Entity Framework 4.1 Code First: Get all Entities with a specific base class

Tags: inheritance, mapping, ef-code-first, entity-framework-4.1, base-class

I have a DbContext with set up different `DbSet<T>`s with all types that derive from the same base class:

```
public class Foo : Entity { }
public class Bar : Entity { }

MyDbContext : DbContext
{
  public DbSet<Foo> Foos { get; set; }
  public DbSet<Bar> Bars { get; set; }
}
```

Is it possible to get all entities which have the `Entity`base class in one query, like:

```
DbContext.Set<Entity>();  // doesn't work
```

I tried to introduce an explicit `DbSet<Entity>` to the DbContext, but that results in one big table for all entities in the database.

Additional question: If this works somehow, what about querying for interfaces?

**Edit:**

I followed the instructions on Ladislav Mrnka's [link](http://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/archive/2011/01/03/inheritance-mapping-strategies-with-entity-framework-code-first-ctp5-part-3-table-per-concrete-type-tpc-and-choosing-strategy-guidelines.aspx) and did my mappings like follows:

```
MyDbContext : DbContext
{
  public DbSet<Entity> Entities { get; set; }

  protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
  {
    // Foo
    modelBuilder.Entity<Foo>().Map(x =>
    {
      x.MapInheritedProperties();
      x.ToTable("Foo");
    })
    .HasMany(x => x.Tags).WithMany();

    modelBuilder.Entity<Foo>()
        .Property(x => x.Id)
        .HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None);

    // Bar
    // same thing for Bar and a bunch of other Entities

    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
  }
}
```

This throws now the error

*The property 'Id' is not a declared property on type 'Foo'. Verify that the property has not been explicitly excluded from the model by using the Ignore method or NotMappedAttribute data annotation. Make sure that it is a valid primitive property.*

I also tried to set the Key explicitly to the `Id` property:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Foo>().Map(x => {...})
  .HasKey(x => x.Id)
  .HasMany(x => x.Tags).WithMany();
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/353284/114029

Comment: Thanks for the link. But seems like this is an answer using the database-first approach wheras I'm looking for a solution with the code-first approach. Maybe am I missing something here, but I don't find any hint for my problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to introduce [TPC inheritance](http://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/archive/2011/01/03/inheritance-mapping-strategies-with-entity-framework-code-first-ctp5-part-3-table-per-concrete-type-tpc-and-choosing-strategy-guidelines.aspx). After that `DbContext.Set<Entity>()` will work and you will still have table per entity.

Comment: Thanks, hoped you would see my question ;-) Looks like what I'm looking for, but haven't got it work yet, fighting with a bunch of errors... right now with _The property 'Id' is not a declared property on type 'Foo'..._. Id is declared in the base class, any idea?

Comment: Sounds like you forgot to use `MapInheritedPropeties` but hard to say when I don't see your mappings.

Comment: I just updated my question with the mappings I tried. Did not forget `MapInheritedProperties`, think I followed the instructions exactly... Maybe I have some additional "special requirements" with my entities... :-)

Comment: Since this gave me the answer to my original question I set this as my accepted answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Just to your problem in your Edit section:

The error message indicates that you have the `Id` key property in your base class `Entity`. Then you need to configure the key property on this class and not on the derived `Foo` class:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Entity>()
    .Property(x => x.Id)
    .HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None);
```

Comment: Makes sense. Now I get the next error: _The type 'Foo' cannot be mapped as defined because it maps inherited properties from types that use entity splitting or another form of inheritance. Either choose a different inheritance mapping strategy so as to not map inherited properties, or change all types in the hierarchy to map inherited properties and to not use splitting._ :-)

Comment: @Dave: No clue, I've never seen this exception. It's likely that it has to do with this part of your mapping of foo: `.HasMany(x => x.Tags)`. What is `Tag`? Is it also derived from your base class? Did you also define TPC mapping for this type?

Comment: Hm, another interpretation: *"it maps inherited properties from types that use ... another form of inheritance"* So, the "types" which `Foo` inherits from is your base class `Entity`. This type uses "another form of inheritance" which could mean that there is another from `Entity` derived type `Foo2` which doesn't map inherited properties. If you didn't configure the mapping for `Foo2` it uses TPH ("another form of inheritance") by default and not TPC. This could mean that you need to configure TPC explicitely for **all** types in the hierarchy to get rid of the exception.

Comment: @Slauma: Tag is also derived from my base class. I also had the suspicion that this could cause the error, so I tried the same with a type `Tag` that doesn't derive from `Entity`. I defined these mappings for all of my types that derive from the base class (including `Tag`). Entity implements two interfaces, maybe that is the problem?

Comment: @Dave: I don't think that the interfaces are a problem. I think you need to simplify your model step by step in an test environment and look when the error disappears. Without seeing your full model it's hard to say what could be wrong. And perhaps make a new question about this problem to get more attention.

Comment: @Slauma: Thanks for your effort!