# Generic constraints and Expression type evaluation

Tags: c#, .net, lambda

This is based on a previous question I had: [EF Code First implemented interface property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9864007/ef-code-first-implemented-interface-property)

I have something like this.

```
interface IKeywordedEntity
{
    ICollection<Keyword> Keywords { get; }
}
class Foo : EntityBase, IKeywordedEntity
{
     public virtual ICollection<Keyword> Keywords { get { ... } }
}
```

The details of `EntityBase` aren't important.

Initially I wrote this extension method to keep things DRY:

```
public static void WithKeywords<TEntityType>(this EntityTypeConfiguration<TEntityType> 
    entityTypeConfiguration) where TEntityType : EntityBase, IKeywordedEntity
{
    entityTypeConfiguration.HasMany(e => e.Keywords).WithMany();
}
```

I would invoke it like so:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Foo>.WithKeywords();
```

However, Entity Framework or the C# compiler is treating `e` in the lambda as `IKeywordedEntity` not `TEntityType`. This freaks out Entity Framework.

Knowing this, I experimented with manually writing the lambda as an `Expression` for `HasMany`. I came up with the following:

```
public static void WithKeywords<TEntityType>(this EntityTypeConfiguration<TEntityType> 
    entityTypeConfiguration) where TEntityType : EntityBase, IKeywordedEntity
{
    var rootExpression = Expression.Parameter(typeof (TEntityType));
    var expression = Expression.Property(rootExpression, "Keywords");

    entityTypeConfiguration.HasMany(Expression.Lambda<Func<TEntityType, ICollection<Keyword>>>(expression, rootExpression)).WithMany();
}
```

Now the IntelliSense is showing me the combination of `EntityBase` and `IKeywordedEntity` correctly and telling me that `e` is `TEntityType`.

My question is: why does the passed/compiled expression tree from the lambda treat `e` as `IKeywordedEntity`, not `TEntityType`?

Answer (score 0):

I'm no expert on Expressions and Lambdas, but this is what I think is going on.

When we just specify a lambda to convert it to an expression tree, the compiler does the work of converting things to the tree. In the method body all the compiler can see is `IKeyworkedEntity.Keywords` not `TEntityType.Keywords` and it uses the explicit property name i.e. uses the following

```
var rootExpression = Expression.Parameter(typeof (IKeyworkedEntity));
var expression = Expression.Property(rootExpression, "Keywords");
```

That is causing the issue which we see. Now if we build the expression tree ourselves, we know that there is a property on the `TEntityType` and we are saying so in the tree. This causes the migration to go through since it sees the property on a class and not on an interface.